# Socket Send(2) - How to send an error message from server to client

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, send, recv

I'm doing some very simple TCP socket programming right now and I have a small problem I can't seem to find the answer to. Basically, what I'm building is a server program and a client program that allow the client to request a file from the server and the server will send it.

My problem is that if the client requests a file that the server doesn't have I need to send an error message back to the client. Is there a flag that I can set to do this? I can't just send a string containing an error message because it is possible that that message could appear in a file transfer at some point and trigger an incorrect response.

I have looked through the MAN pages and some other resources but I couldn't seem to figure it out. I'm working in a Linux environment.

Thank you!

Comment: It's up to you to design the messaging protocol. For example, you could decide that a status will always be sent before the message/data.

Comment: Like having the server send an `OK` reply followed by the file data, or an `ERROR` reply with an error message. Then the client can act according to which reply it receives.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty obvious... Thanks guys. Not sure why I didn't think of that myself.

Comment: Or just implement HTTP. :)

Answer (score 0):

See comments on my original post from kaylum and Remy Lebeau for the solution.